# Grouping and column difference calculating in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to analyze frequency patterns in time series data but there is some technical question. Have a dataframe in Pandas:

```
Date                  Label
2017-03-22 15:16:45   20
2017-03-22 16:12:00   15
2017-03-22 22:10:23   20
2017-03-23 17:00:03   11
2017-03-24 10:11:13   20
2017-03-25 14:02:54   20
```

I would like to calculate the difference between the values in '**Date**' column between each of two values grouping by the label for label '20'. In my view, it should look like timedelta column with the difference and the label column:

```
DateDiff              Label
0 days 06:53:38       20
1 days 12:00:50       20
1 days 03:51:41       20
```

How can it be possible using pandas groupby options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use

```
df.assign(diff=df.groupby('Label')['Date'].diff()).dropna()
```

Output:

```
                 Date  Label            diff
2 2017-03-22 22:10:23     20 0 days 06:53:38
4 2017-03-24 10:11:13     20 1 days 12:00:50
5 2017-03-25 14:02:54     20 1 days 03:51:41
```